# Unignore files ignored with .git/info/exclude

Tags: git, gitignore

I have ignored certain files by editing `.git/info/exclude`.  Now I want to unignore them.  I have edited `.git/info/exclude` to get rid of the corresponding rules, but the files still seem to be ignored.  What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

```
git check-ignore -v path/to/file
```

will show you the rule matching that pathname.